# Codimension-1 submanifold as a inverse image of regular value.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

Let $M$ be a manifold and $N\subset M$ be a codimension-1 submanifold. Is it possible to find a function $H: M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $N\subset H^{-1}(a)$ for some regular value a of $H$?.

If it exists, what is necessary condition for $N=H^{-1}(a)?.$

I have no idea how to proceed it.

Thanks, advance.

Comment: Either way, you'll need the normal bundle of $N$ in $M$ to be trivial. With regard to distinguishing between $=$ and $\subset$, what happens if you take $N$ to be a point and $M=S^1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ted Shifrin remarks, it follows that $N$ has a trivial normal bundle: The tangent space at the regular value pulls back to the normal bundle along $N$ and hence is trivial.

Suppose therefore that $N$ has an orientable normal bundle: Then a neighborhood of $N$ has the form $U\cong: N\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Define $H:U\rightarrow \mathbb R$ via $H(x,t)=t$ and extend it to $M$. Up to a small perturbation outside of $U$ you can assume $H$ has $0$ as a regular value, and it follows that $N\subseteq H^{-1}(0)$.

Now if $M$ and $N$ are connected and $M\setminus N$ has two components then you can extend $f$ to be positive on one component, and negative on the other. In this case $N=H^{-1}(0)$. This is a necessary condition: If $M$ and $N$ are connected and $M\setminus N$ is connected as well you can choose a path from a point $(x,-\epsilon/2)$ to $(x,\epsilon/2)$ that does not traverse $N$. But on this path $H$ assumes both positive and negative values. The intermediate value theorem implies that $H$ must be zero somewhere along this path.

The situation sketched above occurs on the two torus: Take for $N$ a small loop bounding a disc, or take a loop that does not bound a disc.